# Firebase Analytics vs. BigQuery - Average engagement time per screen

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

My engagement time shown in Firebase analytics, under Engagement -> Pages and Screens -> Page Title and Screen Name differs from that which is returned by the following BigQuery query.

```sql
SELECT
  (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key="firebase_screen") AS screen,
  AVG((SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key="engagement_time_msec")) AS avg_engagement_time,
FROM
  `ABC.events_20210923`
GROUP BY screen
ORDER BY avg_engagement_time DESC
```

However the numbers shown in Firebase Analytics are completely different from the numbers returned by the query. The descending order in which they are shown is about 65% right. Is this a completely different metric or is my query just wrong?

Comment: Hi, can yo share some example data? the correct data and the wrong data. so, i can validate the query.

Comment: Same issue here. Did anyone came up with a solution to this already?